# AppSettings, UserSettings, MachineSettings

Tags: c#, configuration, permissions, settings

Every now and then, I run into the problem of providing configuration to a) the users of the application and b) to the application itself.

.Net has it's own settings framework where the configuration is stored XML-based in the `app.settings` file (`user.settings` respectively).

When it comes to `user.setting`s, everything is fine. For every user that uses my applications, an own `user.settings` is being created. The user has permission to change his own settings where it won't affect the application settings or the configuration of other users.

BUT

The general application settings, app.settings is being stored in the assembly folder, mostly `C:\Program Files\\...` when the application is installed. So a regular user is unable to change any settings without admin permissions.

also...

Sometimes I don't want settings bound to a specific application or user, but bound to the computer the application is currently running on. Like license files where I don't want to have every user of a computer activates the application for itself.

In XP, there was the hidden folder `C:\ProgramData` for machine settings, but now in Windows 7/8, it seems that every folder the regular installer creates in there only is writeable with administrator permissions.

How to solve this ridiculous permission problem after all? Is there a way for a regular user to change app.settings, and having global settings for every user seperated from the app.settings, something like a machine.settings?

Comment: Application settings global to all users shouldn't be modifiable by someone without administrator privileges, that's rather the point - only an administrator can make changes that impact other users.

Comment: Generally speaking, you'll want to use wherever %APPDATA% points to - the .NET method is something like Environment.GetFolder (not in a position to google it, sorry)

Comment: How about adding information to the registry? Just a thought